# /usr/local/sbin/php-fpm: Undefined symbol "setproctitle_fast"

Tags: php-fpm, freebsd

After upgrading php7.2 into a php7.4 following error is showing when trying too start a php-fpm service:
`/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm: Undefined symbol "setproctitle_fast"`

Has anybody met this kind of bug in FreeBSD11? Tried to google but couldn't find the solution to fix this problem.

Comment: How exactly did you do the upgrade?

Comment: Just installing php7.4 which removes 7.2 and installs 7.4. The command is: sudo pkg install php74